# Is there a way to include an option to disable Data Replicating in Multiple Fields on Admin Docusign Sandbox API

Tags: docusignapi, electronic-signature

Good day Docusign team and users in Stackoverflow.

Currently my client purchased a program called "FMesignature document edition" a program made through Filemaker [databuzz website] to setup and send information a document through email for signing.

So I use my sandbox developer accuont on Docusign Admin API to setup and test the integration, everything works well except to one thing.

https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Why-is-Data-Replicating-in-Multiple-Fields-Using-Data-Population-Scope

The replicating multiple fields is enabled and wanting to disable it, is there a way that my account unlock this setting?

My client cannot purchase an API plan because of prices being so expensive, he needs other features like personalized branding which works already in the sandbox version.

Is there any staff where I can communicate and unlock this feature? My client is expecting to fully finalized this integration and use on his everyday process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> The replicating multiple fields is enabled and wanting to disable it, is there a way that my account unlock this setting?

Replicating field (tab) values is by design. If you don't want field A's value to be duplicated as field B's value, then give the two fields different `datalabels`

> Using personalized branding

Contact [DocuSign sales](https://www.docusign.com/contact-sales) to discuss which plans include the feature and which do not.